# Android - The method "..." is undefined for the type Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a method called "changeText" inside a fragment class, that would change two TextViews of that fragment, right after the fragment creation.
The problem is that I'am not able to call the method "changeText" from my activity, because I get the error message "The method changeText(String[]) is undefined for the type Fragment", like it doesn't exist.

Where am I doing wrong?

This is my fragment class:

```
package com.example.quizone_2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class fragment_corretto extends Fragment {

TextView questionTv, answerTv;

public fragment_corretto() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_corretto, container,
            false);

    questionTv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    answerTv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.answer);

    return rootView;
}

public void changeText(String[] text){
    questionTv.setText(text[1]);
    answerTv.setText(text[0]);
}

}
```

And this is the method in my activity file, where I call the changeText method:

```
public void answerTrue(View view){

    if(info[2] == "1"){

        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new fragment_corretto();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

        newFragment.changeText(info);

    }else{

        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new Fragment_sbagliato();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

                    newFragment.changeText(info);

    }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, btw I already solved the issue with the answer above, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Activity`, `newFragment` is declared as a `Fragment`. A simple `Fragment` does not have the `changeText` method, or any other method of your subclass for that matter.

The solution is to declare `newFragment` as a `fragment_corretto`:

```
fragment_corretto newFragment = new fragment_corretto();
```

PS. You should follow the convention of using pascal case for naming classes. In other words, don't call it `fragment_corretto`, but rather `FragmentCorretto`

Comment: Unfortunately now I have another problem. The app crashes when it have to replace the fragment, and it do so only if I call the changeText method to replace the text of the TextViews. If i don't call it, the fragment replace the old one without problems (except for the fact that the TextViews have not the text replaced). Do you know why it does this? Thank you very much

Comment: @Artorias a separate issue should be posted as a new question and not a comment. If you do that, be sure to post the logcat's output to help people see where the crash occurred.